# How do I use a Node.js server to continuously push updates of an array to localhost

Tags: javascript, server, push

I create an empty array, drop the value of the first name key from a separate object into it, send it to localhost by creating a server in Node.js, and loop back to pick up new information from another object to push to the array.  But when I loop to the point of hosting on the server on the second loop, I get an error saying "throw error, address already in use at 127.0.0.1:3000

I don't know what alternatives to try to deliver continuous information to a running server

```
var p = 0, repeat = 4
var indices = []

function f() {

//example of array information which is fed into the loop
var mc = [{ name: "Henry", output: -30 }, { name: "Kevin", output: -15 }, { name: "Jeremy", output: -40 }, {name: "Steven", output: 43}]


p++
if (p < repeat) {
setTimeout(f, 100)
}

var open = mc[0].name
indices.push(open)

//this is where the error occurs on the second loop, as the server is already running from the first loop and it can't access the address in use already
var toserver = JSON.stringify(indices)
const http = require('http');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
                        res.statusCode = 200;
                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
                        res.end(toserver);
                    });

                    server.listen(port, hostname, function () {
                        console.log('Server running at http://' + hostname + ':' + port + '/');
                    });

}
f()
```

I get "throw error, address already in use at 127.0.0.1:3000".  I hope someone can show me how to continually update this server.  The information in the array continuously updates and can be seen on console.log.  But it's the updating to the server so I can view it on the browser which is the issue.   Thanks for your kind consideration.

Comment: `address already in use at 127.0.0.1:3000` so, something else is listening on port 3000

Comment: `so I can view it on the browser` ... investigate server side events, or websockets, or just have the browser side "poll" the server at regular intervals

Answer (score 0):

For every cycle you try to create new server therefore in the second run it fails and throws error because you are already listening.

Start the server just once and use websockets or other techniques as Jaromanda suggested.